# CKeditor: Custom Editor options will not load, throws error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am on DNN 08.00.03 (5). The CKeditor version says 3.6.1 (revision 7072). I am on PowerDNN using Control Suite for upgrade package.

When I try and load 'Custom Editor Options' the window that pops up just loads the home page of the site and I get this error. Thanks for any help, Will, Maine USA.

```
AbsoluteURL:/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/CKEditor/Options.aspx

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:fa4d9bb8-951d-476a-828d-bdc4c92b0334

AssemblyVersion:8.0.3

PortalId:2

UserId:1

TabId:74

RawUrl:/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/CKEditor/Options.aspx?mid=6575&tid=3230&minc=txtContent&porid=2&langCode=en-US

Referrer:http://mydomain.tempdomain.com/Home/Websiteadmin/Sandbox/tabid/3230/ctl/Edit/mid/6575/Default.aspx?popUp=true

UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0

ExceptionHash:4Iv979SGl/kEjl8bt458FA==

Message:Unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnTextBox'.

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:Unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnTextBox'.

InnerStackTrace:

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at WatchersNET.CKEditor.Options.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed DNN 08.00.03 (5) for testing and there were no problems with the editor. But the CKEditor version with this version of DNN is 4.5.3. That is probably the issue here. The Options.aspx page probably has some tags that are no longer in use (like dnn:DnnTextBox)

You could try reinstalling CKEditor. Download the latest DNN install package from https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/621771. In the zip file "DNN_Platform_8.0.3_Install.zip" there is a folder "\Install\Provider". Unzip the file "DNNConnect.CKEditorProvider_01.00.02_Install.zip" from this folder and install it like you would a new module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I download that package and install it it is still 3.6.1 (revision 7072). Where is that 4.5.3 version? thanks

Comment: It could be that it installed as a separate editor and was not overwritten since the editor is now supplied by DNNConnect and not from https://dnnckeditor.codeplex.com. In the host menu there should be something like 'HTML Editor manager'. There you can change the default Editor. Chances are that the site still uses the old one.